# Grid Z-order in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I go about putting a grid *in front* of a bar chart in PGFPlots, preferably as automagically as possible? Ed Tufte demonstrates a rather appealing way of drawing bar charts in [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) that consists of removing horizontal grid lines from the bars ([example centre](http://webservices.itcs.umich.edu/mediawiki/Business%20Intelligence/index.php/Bar_chart)), and it occurs to me that this can be replicated by drawing white horizontal lines over the chart, or perhaps through some other route.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this would help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/9562#9562

Comment: Good suggestion, however unfortunately it doesn't. `help lines` can indeed be made to draw on top of the chart, however their spacing has no correspondence to the PGFPlots coordinate system of the chart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an `axis on top` for the `axis` environment that can be used to achieve what you asked for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
  xtick=data,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left,
  axis on top,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style={white}]
\addplot [fill=black] coordinates { (0,2) (1,1.5) (2,3)};
\addplot [draw=black!40,fill=black!40] coordinates { (0,2.2) (1,1.1) (2,5.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar chart with y grid on top]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.